# Extract nested dict value with conditions from JSON using JINJA2 in Ansible

Tags: python, json, ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to extract the CDN domain name for a specific Alias from Ansible's `cloudfront_facts`, with the following (summarized) output:

```
{
  "cdn_facts": {
   "ansible_facts": {
    "cloudfront": {
      "summary": {
       "distributions": [
        {
          "Aliases": [
           "media.example.com"
          ],
          "DomainName": "a1b2c3d4e5f6g.cloudfront.net"
        },
        {
          "Aliases": [
           "example.com"
          ],
          "DomainName": "g7f6e5d4c3b2a.cloudfront.net"
        }
      ]
     }
    }
  }
}
```

In other words, for the Alias `example.com` I'd like to set a fact with the value of `g7f6e5d4c3b2a.cloudfront.net`.

I've tried the following to try and print out the value, but it's simply producing an empty list.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ cdn_facts.ansible_facts.cloudfront.summary.distributions | selectattr('Aliases[0]', 'equalto', 'example.com') | map(attribute='DomainName') | list }}"
```

I'm at a loss on how to even debug this, as `cdn_facts.ansible_facts.cloudfront.summary.distributions` produces an array of dicts, but `selectattr` and `map` are not producing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in your data has an attribute named `Aliases[0]`, so that's why your `selectattr` filter is failing.

For extracting data from deeply nested dictionaries, the `json_query` filter is often a better choice than trying to chain native Jinja filters.  For example, given the alias `example.com`, the following expression will extract the corresponding `DomainName` attribute:

```
cdn_facts.ansible_facts.cloudfront.summary.distributions[?Aliases[0] == `example.com`]|[0].DomainName
```

We can use that in a playbook like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: data.json
        name: data

    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{ item }} ->
          {{
          (data|json_query('cdn_facts.ansible_facts.cloudfront.summary.distributions[?Aliases[0] == `{}`]|[0].DomainName'.format(item)))
          }}
      loop:
        - media.example.com
        - example.com
```

Which will output:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=media.example.com) => {
    "msg": "media.example.com -> a1b2c3d4e5f6g.cloudfront.net"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=example.com) => {
    "msg": "example.com -> g7f6e5d4c3b2a.cloudfront.net"
}
```

The `json_query` modules uses the [jmespath](http://jmespath.org/) search syntax.  You can experiment with jmespath expressions by pasting your data into the text box at https://jmespath.org and then entering search expressions in the field above it.  Alternately, you can grab the [jpterm](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.terminal) command line tool.

Comment: Perfect thank you!  I needed a variable for the predicate in `?Aliases[0] == '{}'` so ended up saving the query first using `set_fact` and then passing the fact to `json_query`.  Worked like a charm!